# Number of Archimedean absolute values?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

This is related to Chpt 4, Sec 4 of Taylor Frohlich, Algebraic Number Theory.

From Ostrowski theorem, any absolute value over $\mathbb Q$ are either equivalent to some $p$-adic absolute value or standard absolute value.

$S$ is a finite set of inequivalent of absolute values of $K$ which includes only all Archimedean absolute values.

In particular, I pick $S$ coinciding with the set of all Archimedean absolute values extending $\mathbb Q$'s Archimedean absolute values. Then $U_K(S)=\{a\in K^\star \mid \forall v\not\in S,\ |a|_v=1\}=\mu_K\times \mathbb Z^{|S|-1}$. Here $K$ is a number field.

$\textbf{Q:}$ For $K / \mathbb Q$, it is clear that there are only finitely many absolute values extending the Archimedean absolute value $|x|$. In general, is there an example with infinite number Archimedean absolute values for a finite extension over some field other than $\mathbb Q$? (It is clear it cannot be extension of number fields or between number fields.)

$\textbf{Q':}$ My guess is that $\mathbb C/ \mathbb Q$ has infinite Archimedean absolute values extending over $\mathbb Q$. However, I am not sure this is correct in the sense that $\mathbb C$ should be realized as inverse limit of finite Galois group associated to $\mathbb C$ as a field.

Comment: If your $C$ is the complex numbers $\mathbb C$, then since most elements of $\mathbb C$ are not algebraic over $\mathbb Q$, the nature of the issue changes significantly.

Comment: @paulgarrett If I have a standard absolute value and $K/Q$ is a complex field extension or $K\not\subset Q$, then I would have $K$ completion as $C$ rather than $\bar{Q}$. That is why I thought $C$ is a more reasonable choice rather than $\bar{Q}$. Should I replace $C$ by $\bar{Q}$ instead? Then I would consider $\bar{Q}\otimes_Q R$ which I hope to yield distinct absolute values.

Comment: There is a potential confusion about order of operations: $\mathbb C$ itself has a unique (reasonable) topology. For a totally complex (finite, that is, algebraic) extension $k$ of $\mathbb Q$, e.g., a cyclotomic field, yes, all the archimedean completions of $k$ are isomorphic to $\mathbb C$. Similarly, any finite extension of $\mathbb Q_p$ has a unique compatible topology. So one does not want to ask your question in a fashion that is thwarted by those facts...

Comment: Consider the formula $n=r_1+2r_2$ where $n$  is the degree of the number field, and $r_1$ and $r_2$ are the numbers of real, resp. complex absolute values of the field. This tells me that any field of algebraic numbers that is infinite over the rationals has to have infinitely many Archimedean places. Make sense?

Comment: @Lubin Yes. That is indeed the case. The question was dumb. Thanks.

Comment: @paulgarrett Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Not so dumb. There are still a few facts to check before my argument goes through. But they are easy, I believe.